# Double arrow with text over it that extends to fit text (that is, a "\xRightarrow")

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrows

I know it's possible to have `\xrightarrow (text)`, but if I try to do `\xRightarrow (text)` I get an error each time. Does anybody know if it's a syntax error or if there is a other way to produce the `\Rightarrow` with text above?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[image]

Just taking the definition of `\xrightarrow` and replacing `r` by `R` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xRightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\Rightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% To create a single arrow with text above, use lowercase "r".
$\xrightarrow{\mathit{hello}}$

% To create a double arrow with text above, use uppercase "R".
$\xRightarrow{\mathit{hello}}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: oh, please at least make that `\mathit{hello}` to get rid of the obnoxious math kerning.

Comment: As I posted I felt your pain but I had to dash:-)

Comment: how do you choose the single arrow when making the command? copy pasting your code (that has no explanation) yields the double arrow.

Comment: @CharlieParker I'm not sure I understand your question, my answer shows two arrows, the single one `\xrightarrow` is a standard command from amsmath just shown for comparison, and the double arrow version with capital R  which is defined here.

Answer (score 52):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\xrightarrow{\text{hello}}$
$\xRightarrow{\text{hello}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the difference in arrow lengths? The head of the double arrow is under "o" of hello, while "hello" is entirely above the shaft of the single arrow.

Comment: This has now been corrected in ``mathtools`` (and in the image above).

Answer (score 10):

You can also use underset and overset:

```
$\underset{\text{hello}} \longrightarrow$

$\overset{\text{hello}} \longrightarrow$

$\underset{\tiny\text{hello}} \longrightarrow$

$\overset{\tiny\text{hello}} \longrightarrow$
```

Comment: This solution does not create arrows that grow to accommodate what's over/under them.