# How do I rotate arrows, write text on it and then position the text correctly?

Tags: arrows, rotating

I know it's a little localized, but bear with me as I need to know how to do this. Here's an image of what I have to do: [image]

So as you can see I have to draw these lines. I know [how to add text on them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text) and how to rotate them (\turn), but how can I position the second line text correctly?

**UPDATE:** I also need to have double arrows like this:
[image]

Comment: I guess I could also use tikz-cd, couldn't I?

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. i.e., what is in the image provided leaving out the non-horizontal arrows?

Comment: Well I tried the first example I read in the manual, but it used square braces which gave an error. So IMHO the manual is outdated. I thought I could use shift left, but is there some automagical way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be waiting for a `tikz-cd`-solution (Thanks to Bernard for typing all the formulae from your drawing):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0.6cm]
        \ce{Cr} \arrow{r}{1} & \ce{Cr2O3} \arrow{r} \arrow{dr}[swap]{5} & \ce{CrCl3} \arrow{r}{3} & \ce{Cr(OH)3} \arrow{dl} \arrow{r}{4} \arrow{d}{7} & \ce{Cr2O3}\\
        & &\ce{KCrO2} \arrow{r}{6} & \ce{Cr(NO3)3} &
    \end{tikzcd}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to rotate the number 5 to the same angle of the arrow, you may write `\arrow{dr}[swap,sloped]{5}`.

---

**Edit**:

For your second picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document} 
    \[   
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \ce{Al2(SO4)3} \arrow[shift left]{r}{2} & \ce{Al(OH)3} \arrow[shift left]{l}{7} 
    \end{tikzcd} 
    \]   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Im getting undefined control sequence

Comment: I changed \ce to \ch, sorry

Comment: Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: \ch{Al2O3} \arrow{r}{1} & \ch{Al2(SO4)3} \arrow[yshift=0.667ex]{r}{2} & \ch{Al(OH)3} \arrow[shift left=0.667ex]{l}{7}

Comment: @user2563892 Please updated your TeX-distribution. I am not getting any error with the above code. I do not understand your last comment. Why hard code it, when it does look good as it is and why not use `shift left` twice. And you are using `\ch` and not `\ce` so I have to suppose that you haven't compiled the MWE I posted.

Comment: So the tex distribution is the problem, ok. The second code is what works for me. How can I update it? I run an apt-get upgrade every week so I dont think it could be that outdated. And also, I did compile your MWE.

Answer (score 3):

With the `mhchem` and `pst-node` packages,it's easy. Note tha the `pdf` option lets you compile with `pdflatex` provided  you compile with the `-shell-escape (for TeX Live or MacTeX) or`--enable-write18` (for MiKTeX) switch.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{report}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{arrows = ->, nodesep = 3pt, labelsep = 3pt, colsep = 1.2cm, rowsep = 1.2cm, npos = 0.45, arrowinset=0.2}
\begin{psmatrix}
 \ce{Cr} & \ce{Cr2O3} & \ce{CrCl3} &\ce{Cr(OH)3} & \ce{Cr2O3}\\
 & &\ce{KCrO2} & \ce{Cr(NO3)3}\\[0.5cm]
\ce{Al2(SO4)3} & \ce{Al(OH)3}
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput{1} \ncline{1,2}{1,3} \ncline{1,3}{1,4}\naput{3}\ncline{1,4}{1,5}\naput{4}
 \ncline{1,2}{2,3}\naput[npos=0.5]{5}\ncline{1,4}{2,3}\ncline{1,4}{2,4}\naput{7}
 \ncline{2,3}{2,4}\naput{6}
%
\psset{tpos = 0.52}
\ncline[offset=0.667ex]{3,1}{3,2}\taput{2}\ncline[offset=0.667ex]{3,2}{3,1}\tbput{7}
\end{psmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is ok, but the other one with tikz-cd seems a bit easier

Comment: @user2563892: It's a different philosophy: in `psmatrix`, one defines first the nodes, then the links between nodes. With `tikz-cd`, nodes and links are mixed. I also use tikz-cd from time to time, but I find `pstricks` generally easier to customise, because its syntax is closer to LaTeX's.

Comment: OK, but I actually need more help and here's the customizability that might come in handy. I'll update question in a moment and you'll see.

Comment: @user2563892: See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now I'm stuck, how do I vote both answers? :)

Comment: @user2563892: That's not a problem: I'm here to help, not to compete.