# Stretch \Leftrightarrow according to above text

Tags: equations, arrows, text

Currently I'm using

```
\newcommand{\Leftrightarrowtext}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\text{#1}}{\Leftrightarrow}}}
```

to add text above an equivalence sign (like *Def. 5.11*, etc), but I would like the equivalence sign to stretch with the text. This is different than \xRightarrow, since I want equivalence and can't find an `\xLeftrightarrow` command.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

Use the command

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xLeftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0099\Leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

This is a variation of the [answer to "\xRightarrow (text)"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85115/110998).

The following output is obtained by the code below it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xLeftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0099\Leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$A \xLeftrightarrow{\mathit{hello}} B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you I'll accept the answer as soon as I can. How did you come up with this?

Comment: In your previous posting, @egreg was basically right that your question has been answered before, in a different setting. He was not right in closing it as an "exact duplicate" because it requires a modification that cannot be expected from every user of LaTeX.

Comment: Hmm, there's an evident asymmetry. You probably want `0099`. The fix is straightforward nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the fix. But there are still some numbers left that we could try.

Comment: @egreg If "straightforward" is tongue-in-cheek, agreed. If it was meant as a serious remark, I'd have to object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version to  be found in the excellent document [Math Mode](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) by Herbert Voß (with a modification of parameters), at § 38, Extensible Arrows, pp.78-79:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xLongLeftRightArrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0099{\LongLeftRightArrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\LongLeftRightArrowfill@{%
  \arrowfill@\Leftarrow\Relbar\Rightarrow}
\makeatother
```

The 4 digit parameter denotes:

1st digit: space left

2nd digit: space right

3rd digit space  left and right

4th digit; space relative to the arrow tips.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xLongLeftRightArrow[2][]%
  {\ext@arrow 0099{\LongLeftRightArrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\LongLeftRightArrowfill@
  {\arrowfill@\Leftarrow\Relbar\Rightarrow}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$A \xLongLeftRightArrow[\text{very long sentence}]%
                       {\text{This is a very very}} B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: In what does this differ from the other answer, apart from overcomplicating the code?

Comment: @egreg: I wanted to mention Herbert Voss' document, which gives detailed explanations on how to obtain extensible arrows of all sorts with some basic components.