# \xrightsquigarrow{text}

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrows

This question is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text), but I didn't manage to adapt the proposed answer to this case.

I would like to create a command similar to `\xrightarrow{text}` but with the arrow `\rightsquigarrow` instead of `\rightarrow`. I guess there is an easy way to modify the `\xrightarrow` command, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? Do you want a straight line with the `\rightsquigarrow` head, or should the whole line be squiggly? (For the latter see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60216/82917.)

Comment: @campa I would like to have the whole line be squiggly. I looked at the link. It is indeed a similar question, but I would like to avoid using tikz if possible.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow (no `tikz`)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the answer into this link [\xRightarrow (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text) and declare a new command that I named with `\xra` (for the `\rightsquigarrow`) and `\xla` (for the `\leftsquigarrow`).

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand{\xra}[1]{\overset{#1}{\rightsquigarrow}}
\newcommand{\xla}[1]{\overset{#1}{\leftsquigarrow}}
\begin{document} 
I love cheese, especially everyone loves cow. Pepper jack cut the cheese cheesy feet cheeseburger danish fontina cheesy feet taleggio airedale. Croque monsieur roquefort cottage cheese jarlsberg cheesy feet pepper jack jarlsberg bocconcini. Ricotta monterey jack cheese triangles goat lancashire st. agur blue cheese.
\[\xra{\text{cheese}}\]
Swiss edam cheese strings. Airedale boursin rubber cheese hard cheese say cheese jarlsberg melted cheese cottage cheese. Cheesecake fromage frais edam chalk and cheese $\xla{\text{hamburger}}$ red leicester chalk and cheese red leicester who moved my cheese. Cheeseburger cheese strings airedale cheeseburger paneer.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the `stix` package changes the font of your document, though.

Comment: @epsilone Yes, of course. It is possible to find the symbol into your slot number and declare a newcommand.

Comment: @epsilone Done, and thank you very much for your comment.