# Make the arrow of \xrightarrow an hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, arrows, hyperlink

I order not to loose the reader of a big document with a lot of new notations, I make each of the notations I introduce an hyperlink to the place it is defined, so at any time, the reader can refer to the definition (in particular when notations are overloaded).

One of the notation I use is a labeled arrow using `\xrightarrow` from `amsmath` [1], and I'd like the arrow to be an hyperlink to its definition, but not the label (for external reasons, mainly the label itself should sometimes be a reference to elsewhere).

Of course, embedding the whole `\xrightarrow` in a `\hyperlink{...}` also makes the label a link, which I do not want (see the example below, I use `colorlinks=true` to emphasize which part is a link and which is not).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true
}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[\hypertarget{Arrow}{Arrow}]
    Here I define \(A\xrightarrow{\text{\rm long label}} B\).
\end{definition}

\[A \hyperlink{Arrow}{\xrightarrow{\textrm{long label}}} B\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the code above, we see that both the arrow and the label are in red, i.e. are links.]

Looking at other questions about `\xrightarrow` (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text#85115)), it seems to be doable by (worst case) redefining the command, but I'm not comfortable enough with `amsmath` to do it. Also, I checked the `hyperref` manual for a command to exclude some text from a label (to do something like `hyperlink{Arrow}{\xrightarrow{\exclude{\text{long label}}}}`, but I couldn't find such command.

---

Remarks: The question is about unlinking the label, not just removing the color (which was added in the MWE to clarify the problem, but won't be turned on in the end).

---

[1] The context is that I define the transitions of a labeled transition system (for computer scientists).

Comment: do you actually need the label unlinked, or just uncoloured (which is easier)

Comment: unrelated but I'd use `\textrm` here not `\text` so you get a consistent font not italic in the definition.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need the label unlinked (color will be disabled anyway in the end, I put it here just for emphasize). For the label, this was just to illustrate (in practice, labels are also math, not text), but I'll edit that :-)

Comment: links in pdf are really just rectangular regions somewhat separate from but overlayed over the text so actually there isn't a lot of difference between having the text linked or not linked, it just makes the link rectangle a bit taller

Comment: Yes, I read @Ulrike answer below which also explains that. My understanding of links was wrong, so thank both of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links doesn't link "content". They only add a rectangle annotation box. The content is only relevant to decide how large the box should be. So if you want a smaller link area you need to hide the content that should not contribute to the box. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    %colorlinks=true %show box
}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[\hypertarget{Arrow}{Arrow}]
    Here I define \(A\xrightarrow{\text{long label}} B\).
\end{definition}

\[A \xrightarrow{\text{long label}}
    \llap{\hyperlink{Arrow}{\hphantom{$\xrightarrow{\text{long label}}$}\rule{0pt}{4pt}}\kern2pt} B\]

\end{document}
```

The main problem is that it is rather difficult to add this without disturbing the math spacing.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks! I actually though that links where linking content, and that the default red box of hyperref was an intentionnally bigger area to ease clicking on the links. Now you mentionned it, I indeed noticed that even with `colorlinks=true`, the linking area is a rectangle (typically, in the white upper right/left corners). I really appreciate this kind of answers which not only gives what one need, but also corrects the fallacies one has for a long time.