# Extensible negated arrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows

Similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text), I want to write some text above `$\nrightarrow$`. This is what I could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    
    
    $\nrightarrow$
    
    $\nrightarrow^{\text{Hello}}$
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the text is not properly aligned.

[image]

So, I seek help in putting the text right on top.

Additionally, it would be appreciated to faciliate extending the arrow to fit the text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xnrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vphantom{\xrightarrow[#1]{#2}}%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth\neg@arrow\hidewidth\cr$\m@th\xrightarrow[#1]{#2}$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\neg@arrow}{%
  $\m@th\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\scalebox{1.5}[1]{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle|$}}%
  }}$
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A\xnrightarrow{\text{hello}}B \\
A\xnrightarrow{\text{hello again}}B
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

where a negation symbol is superimposed to the standard `\xrightarrow`. The negation symbol is a fattened bar which is rotated.

[image]

Comment: remove "maybe" :). assume that he is wanting it, OP would edit the question or comment you about if it wasn't the solution.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy Maybe, "maybe" is just politeness!

Comment: @VScode_fanboy If nothing better comes along…

Comment: @egreg Yeah of course. No need to change it even if it is accepted. EDIT: it IS.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `\substack` is an option for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
    \substack{Hello\\\nrightarrow}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See the word `Extensible` in the OPs question. This solution does not provide an extensible negated arrow

Comment: @daleif  _Maybe `\substack` is an option for you:_ He probably thought that his answer will be helpful if this the only way or no other answer or hope that OP might use this for his solution. But of course this is not an direct-answer, but that's the point of _maybe `\lorem` is an option_...