# How to write mathematical expression above arrow

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write this mathematical expression `$n, m \in N \leq G$`
on `\Rightarrow` (as a list item) while writing proof.

But in this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Beweis:}

\begin{itemize}
\item[i.]nehme an, dass $x \in Ng \cap Nh \neq \phi.$

\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\Rightarrow$] $x = ng$ und $x = mh$ für passende $m,n \in N$ dann $x \in Ng$ und $x \in Nh.$
    \item[$\Rightarrow$] $ng = x = mh.$
    \item[\xRightarrow{$n,m \in N \leq G$}] $g = n^{-1}mh \wedge h = m^{-1}ng$
    \item[$\Rightarrow$] $Ng = N(n^{-1}mh) \subseteq Nh \\ Nh = N(m^{-1}ng \subseteq Ng.$
\end{itemize}

\item[ii.] $Hx = Hy \Leftrightarrow H = Hyx^{-1} \Leftrightarrow yx^{-1} \in H.$

\item[iii.] $|Hx| = |H|$

\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\Rightarrow$] Dann: $Hx \subseteq G, x \in G, H \leq G.$
    \item[$\Rightarrow$] $|Hx| \leq |H|$ auch $hx = gx \Leftrightarrow h = g.$
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The output is like this
[image]

How do I get the desired result?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: I think it's not defined by default though, you need the definition, use one of the solutions in [math mode - \xRightarrow (text) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text#85115)

Comment: Thanks @user202729 but I'm looking to write a mathematical expression.

Comment: Can you please manipulate your screenshot and add it, how your desired result should look like? Thanks

Comment: How not using enumerate instead if itemize? Avoid editing `\item`s locally all the time.  Package [enumitem](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) should be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following MWE applies `\xRightarrow{}` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85115/140133) to write some math above `$\Rightarrow$` and the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to reduce the amount of local editions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xRightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\Rightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Beweis:}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.]
  \item nehme an, dass $x \in Ng \cap Nh \neq \phi.$
  
  \begin{itemize}[label=$\Rightarrow$]
    \item $x = ng$ und $x = mh$ für passende $m,n \in N$ dann $x \in Ng$ und $x \in Nh.$
    \item $ng = x = mh.$
    \item[$\xRightarrow{n,m \in N \leq G}$] $g = n^{-1}mh \wedge h = m^{-1}ng$
    \item $Ng = N(n^{-1}mh) \subseteq Nh \\ Nh = N(m^{-1}ng \subseteq Ng.$
  \end{itemize}
  
  \item $Hx = Hy \Leftrightarrow H = Hyx^{-1} \Leftrightarrow yx^{-1} \in H.$
  
  \item $|Hx| = |H|$
  
  \begin{itemize}[label=$\Rightarrow$]
    \item Dann: $Hx \subseteq G, x \in G, H \leq G.$
    \item $|Hx| \leq |H|$ auch $hx = gx \Leftrightarrow h = g.$
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use the same standard for labeling steps, considere creating a new environment for `\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.] ... \end{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of using of `mathtools.sty` and the tag is `\xrightarrow` and the `MWE` is

```
$\xrightarrow{a+b=c}$
```

Comment: `amsmath` is enough.

Comment: Spelling: `\xrightarrow`.

Comment: Sorry i was in my mobile there are no key for backslash